# MSAccess Slow Updates on Self-Joined table

Tags: sql, ms-access, self-join, sqlperformance

I am trying to improve the performance of updating only about 60K rows with data coming from different rows in the same table.  At about 2 minutes, it's not terrible, but it's not great either, and my application really doesn't work if you have to wait so long between recalculations.

The app generates a set of financial statements for a business, where it calculates basic formulas on 1300 line items, like Rent, or Direct Labor, or Inventory costs, all of which roll up to totals that mimic the Balance Sheet, P&Ls, Cash Flow etc.  Many of the line items need to calculate on a month by month basis, where for instance it has figure out April's On Hand Inventory before knowing what April's Inventory Value is.  So the total program ends up looping through 48 months over 30 calculation passes, requiring about 8000 SQL statements. (fortunately it figures it all out by itself!) Each SQL is taking only a few milliseconds, but it adds up.

I'm pretty sure I can't reduce the number of loops, so I keep trying to figure out how to make each SQL quicker. The basic structure is as follows:

**LI:** Line item table that holds the basic info of each item, primary key LID

```
LID   Name
123   Sales_1 
124   Sales_2
200   Total Sales
```

**Formula:** Master/Detail tables that create any formula from the line items

```
Total sales=Sales_1 + Sales_2
or
{200}={123}+{124}
```

(I use curly braces to be able to find and replace the LIDs within the formula, as shown in the SQL below)

**FC:** Formula Calculation table: all line items by month, about 1300 items x 48 months=62K records.  Primary key FID

```
FID   SQL_ID LID  LID_brace  LIN       OutputMonth  Formula       Amount
3232  25     123  {123}      Sales_1         1                      1200
3255  26     124  {124}      Sales_2         1                      1500
5454  177    200  {200}      Total Sales     1      {123}+{124}
```

**DMO**:Operand Join table, which links a formula to its detail lines within the same table, so once Sales_1 is calculated, it can find the Total Sales record and update it, which then will evaluate then send its amount up the chain to the other LIDs that depend on it, such as Total Income. It locates the record to update based on the SQL_id, which is set based on the calc pass and month.  Its complex to setup, but pretty straightforward once you actually run things

```
Master_FID  Detail_FID  
5454         3232            (links total sales to sales_1)
5454         3255            (links total sales to sales_2)
```

**SQL1:**

```
Update FC inner join DMO on FC.FID=DMO.Master_FID inner join FC2 on DMO.Detail_FID=FC2.FID set FC.formula=replace(FC.Formula,FC.LID_brace,FC2.Amount) where FC.sql_id=177
```

The above will change {123} + {124}  to 1200+1500 which will then evaluate to 2700 when I run the following

**SQL2**:

```
UPDATE FC SET FC.amount = Eval([fc].[formula]) WHERE (((FC.calc_sql_id)=177 )
```

So those two sql statements are run over and over again, with the only thing changing is the SQL_id.
There are indexes on the SQL_ID, LID, FID etc

When measuring, the milliseconds per record can range from .04ms if there are many records included (~10K for some passes), up to 10 or 15 ms for just one record updated.  Perhaps it is the setup of the query causing a whole lot of overhead time, because it doesn't seem to be a function of the actual number of records updated?  Also its not very consistent, where some runs have 20+ ms compared to less than 3ms when it runs it again.

I know this is a complex question i'm asking that probably doesn't have a simple answer, but I'm just looking for directions for what might help.  For instance, a parameter query if there isn't a whole lot of change between runs?  Does Access have a better time of running a query if knows about it in advance, i.e a named query with parameters vs dynamic SQL?  Am I just doomed because it still needs to run those 8000 queries?

Also, is there inherently a problem with trying to update the same table through a secondary join table, and/or is there a better way to do it?

Is it also because string replacing isn't efficient this way?  If I tried RegEx would that be quicker?  I would have to make a function that could do that within a query, but it seems like that's going to be slower.

Thanks in advance, this has been a most vexing problem!!!

Comment: You really should not `Eval` if you want performance (or pretty much ever). Even building your own expression parser is likely to be faster than repeatedly compiling individual statements to VBA and then executing them. And likely executing this whole thing through VBA would be faster, since you're repetitively executing VBA anyway.

Comment: Thanks, I'm not sure i can improve on Eval, especially since the idea is that any valid formula could be used, including functions such as IF or Round.  it would be too hard to parse all to possibilities accurately and efficiently.  is Eval a really slow function?

Comment: I just reran everything with a bypass for the Eval, where it just returns 0 instead of actually doing anything, and it shaved only 2 seconds out of 30 seconds for the 4000 or so stmts that do the evaluation part.  it may simply be that the overhead of looping through 8000 stmts is my big problem...argh

Comment: Looks weird, but maybe I got you wrong.`Sales_1`are the sales for item1, or what else?`Why aren't`Total_Sales`the sum of all sales? Mayve you need an extra table to connect the relevant single sales for the total instead of a formular. Show more data and expected results.

Comment: Yes Sales_1 indicates for one kind of product, Sales_2 for another.  I have about 10 products im selling, so the final formula for the total_sales would be the sum of all products.  but i have other formulas for costs, on hand, built units, etc, about 1300 line items in total.  All line items can be part of additional formulas, hence the join table that matches a line item with its formula operands

Comment: I worry that there really isn't a way to improve on having to run all the sql statements in sequence

Comment: Still waiting for  more data and expected results. Then we can create a data model that allows usual sql queries without replacing

Comment: Hi thanks for your support.  Not sure how much detail you need and whether i can simplify enough to be reasonable to post via text here.  would a sample accdb file be appropriate?   The idea again is that I'm trying to build a linked set of calculations, where the result of one is passed up as an operand to the next calculation uptree.  I thought i had gotten it to be as efficient as possible, while keeping total flexibility by converting each formula's operand's line item id to it's actual value, then evaluating using the Eval formula.  not sure how to describe it here without the actual code

Comment: I found a solution that is pretty cool and may help others.  For sure, looping through 8000 sql stmts is a bottleneck, but the issue is that i need to do things in order, plus i need to take the results of the initial eval update and pass it uptree to whatever other record needs the value.   I realized that i can force an update in sequence by linking to a sorted set first (i.e  Select xxx from (select id from my_table order by sortorder) A inner join my_table B on A.id=B.id set B.amount=eval(B.formula) which gets the formulas evaluated in sequence

Comment: The second part was to include functions within the sql statement, so that instead of just Eval, it will run an Eval2 function which will not just return the value, but store it in a global array that i can then reference when doing the second half of the process with a second function, namely updating the formula uptree.  Thus I'm able to calculate thousands of step by step updates with one SQL command.  I was able to reduce my time by a factor of 4, plus it scales well with new data.

Comment: Essentially the SQL is: